# Error in the code saying cannot convert bstNode* to bstNode** . I am using the concept of double pointer here alongwith recursion

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>


     struct bstNode
     {
     int data;
     struct bstNode *left;
     struct bstNode *right;
     };



     struct bstNode* getNewNode(int data)
     {
     struct bstNode* newNode = (struct bstNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct bstNode));
      newNode->data = data;
     newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
     return newNode;
     }

     void Insert(struct bstNode** root, int data)
     {
        if(*root == NULL)
       {
           *root = getNewNode(data);
     }

     else
     if(data >= (*root)->data)
     {
         Insert((*root)->right, data);
     }
     else
     {
         Insert((*root)->left, data);
     }
 }

 void Search(struct bstNode** root,int data)
 {
     if(data == (*root)->data)
     {
         printf("Data Found");
         getchar();
         exit(0);
     }

     else
     if(data >= (*root)->data)
     {
         Search((*root)->left, data);
     }
     else
     {
         Search((*root)->right, data);
     }
 }

 int main()
 {
     struct bstNode* root = NULL;
     Insert(&root,12);
     Insert(&root,13);
     Insert(&root,1);
     Insert(&root,16);
     Insert(&root,8);
     Insert(&root,19);

     Search(&root,8);
     Search(&root,6);

     return 0;
 }
```

In the above code, I am trying to pass the address of the pointer variable from the main function to Insert function.As far as my knowledge, here it should accept the arguments as pointer to pointer but its not accepting . What is the problem ? Please help so that I can update my knowledge as well. Thank You.

The detailed error is as follows:

main.cpp: In function ‘void Insert(bstNode**, int)’:
main.cpp:32:37: error: cannot convert ‘bstNode*’ to ‘bstNode**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void Insert(bstNode**, int)’
          Insert((*root)->right, data);
                                     ^

main.cpp:36:36: error: cannot convert ‘bstNode*’ to ‘bstNode**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void Insert(bstNode**, int)’
          Insert((*root)->left, data);
                                    ^
main.cpp: In function ‘void Search(bstNode**, int)’:
main.cpp:52:36: error: cannot convert ‘bstNode*’ to ‘bstNode**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void Search(bstNode**, int)’
          Search((*root)->left, data);
                                    ^

main.cpp:56:37: error: cannot convert ‘bstNode*’ to ‘bstNode**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void Search(bstNode**, int)’
          Search((*root)->right, data);
                                     ^

Comment: Please give the exact and full error message.

Comment: I suspect your error is not at the `Insert` calls as you seem to suggest. That's why we need the full error msgs. Looks like it is the `Search` calls that are wrong.

Comment: I have posted the full error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **EXPLANATION**

You have missed out an `&` before `(*root)->left` and `(*root)->right` inside multiple `Insert` and `Search` function calls. I have modified your program and added the required `&` address of operators. Now it compiles fine.

But the code you have posted results in a segmentation fault, even after rectifying the type errors. This is because, as I had mentioned in my comments, there were multiple **logical errors** in your program. I have listed them below:

- You had not specified termination criteria for recursion inside the `Search` function. The recursive search ultimately resulted in a `Segmentation Fault`.
- You were using wrong arguments for recursively calling the `Search` function inside `else if` and `else`. If `data < *root -> data`, it means that the current element (*root -> data) is larger in comparison to the value you are looking for and hence, you have to look further in the left sub-tree and skip the right sub-tree. The case becomes the opposite when `data > *root -> data`. But you were looking in the right sub-tree when `data < *root -> data` and vice-versa. This led to an incorrect search.
- Although not an error, you are using `exit(0)` when you find the searched value in the BST. This will immediately terminate the program and hence, you can only use `Search` inside the main function once if the value is present in the BST.
- You had no message indicating the value is not present in the BST.

The modifications I have made include:

- A terminating condition for recursive search inside the `Search` function, i.e. checking is `*root == NULL`
- Interchanging the arguments for recursive `Search` calls.
- Adding a message to determine when the value is not present in BST
- Added a commented Search for checking for a value not present in BST

Below is the final working version of your code with the modifications. I would suggest you get rid of the `exit(0)` and replace it with some other mechanism.

> **MODIFIED WORKING CODE**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct bstNode
    {
        int data;
        struct bstNode *left;
        struct bstNode *right;
    };

    struct bstNode *getNewNode(int data)
    {
        struct bstNode *newNode = (struct bstNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct bstNode));
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
        return newNode;
    }

    void Insert(struct bstNode **root, int data)
    {
        if (*root == NULL)
        {
            *root = getNewNode(data);
        }

        else if (data >= (*root)->data)
        {
            Insert(&((*root)->right), data);
        }
        else
        {
            Insert(&((*root)->left), data);
        }
    }

    void Search(struct bstNode **root, int data)
    {
        if (*root != NULL)
        {
            if (data == (*root)->data)
            {
                printf("Data Found");
                getchar();
                exit(0);
            }

            else if (data > (*root)->data)
            {
                Search(&((*root)->right), data);
            }
            else
            {
                Search(&((*root)->left), data);
            }
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        struct bstNode *root = NULL;
        Insert(&root, 12);
        Insert(&root, 13);
        Insert(&root, 1);
        Insert(&root, 16);
        Insert(&root, 8);
        Insert(&root, 19);

        Search(&root, 8);
        // Search(&root, 29);
        printf("Data Not Found");

        return 0;
    }
```

Here is a working solution achieving the same goal, without using double referencing (`**`).

> **MY SOLUTION**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

struct node *createNode(value){
    struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}


struct node *insert(struct node *root, int data)
{
    if (root == NULL) return createNode(data);

    if (data < root->data)
        root->left  = insert(root->left, data);

    else if (data > root->data)
        root->right = insert(root->right, data);   

    return root;
}

void search(struct node *root, int data, int *found){
    if(root == NULL) return;

    search(root->left, data, found);

    if(root->data == data){
        *found = 1;
    } 

    search(root->right, data, found);
}

int main(){
    struct node *root = NULL;

    root = insert(root, 8);
    insert(root, 3);
    insert(root, 1);
    insert(root, 6);
    insert(root, 7);
    insert(root, 10);
    insert(root, 14);
    insert(root, 4);

    int found7 = 0, found9 = 0;
    search(root, 7, &found7);
    search(root, 9, &found9);

    found7 ? printf("7 found in BST\n") : printf("7 not found\n");

    found9 ? printf("9 found in BST\n") : printf("9 not found\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Showing Segmentation fault core dumped. Why ?

Comment: @JavedAnsari There's some logical error with your code. See if you can analyze it and rectify it. It is probably attributed to the fact that using double pointers heightens the code complexity and makes debugging a tad more difficult. I have rewritten the code without using double pointers and provided it below my answer as an edit. I hope that helps. If it does, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Yeah I have done it what you are telling me. But that's not the problem, Actually I want to know why the error is occuring if I use double pointer ?

Comment: @JavedAnsari Let me take a look then

Comment: @JavedAnsari I have found the logical errors. I have made an edit to my answer pointing them out and why the Segmentation fault was caused. I have modified your code with minimal changes to make it work correctly. I hope that leaves no room for doubt and this answer can be accepted.

Comment: A lot of Thanks Aakash for clarifying my doubts.

Comment: @JavedAnsari Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

In if statements of your functions like this

```
 if(data >= (*root)->data)
 {
     Insert((*root)->right, data);
 }
 else
 {
     Insert((*root)->left, data);
 }
```

for example the expression `(*root)->right` has the type `struct bstNode*` but the function expects an argument of the type `struct bstNode**`. Change this statement and similar statements like

```
     Insert( &(*root)->right, data);
```

Comment: same as Search function

Comment: @idris I wrote that in all statements like this.